# How to start a process instance from another project within the same solution, getting required info programmatically

Tags: c#, visual-studio, process

So basically, I have a winforms solution. It has several projects some are either dll's or .exe's. The main project has project references to all of the other secondary projects. From the Main project I want to run an instance of a process that represents a compiled .exe file from one of the other projects.

I wanted to do this using process.Start(), But I  would prefer to reference it programmatically rather than typing out C:\user\solutions\solutionname\project2\bin\release\project2.exe. Is there a way to get this info programmatically since I have the other projects as references?

Comment: If you referenced them in your main project then you can call them by initiating their base class. For instance to call another WF app you would do something like this. var MyOtherWFProject = new MyOtherProjectName.AFormInMyProject(); MyOtherWFProject.show(); etc

Comment: I already know how to do that. I am talking about running them on a separate process via process.start() . Instead of passing in  C:\user\solutions\solutionname\project2\bin\release\project2.exe , I was wondering if there was a way to get that info programmatically. Like some sort of assembly info reflection or something.

Comment: I mean if I were to go into windows task manager, I would see a separate processes one for each .exe running. What you are suggesting puts them on the same process, and thus they share the same threadpool, and if the process were terminated all forms spawned only via instantiation i.e. new form() would also be terminated.

Comment: To quote an article: The thread pool architecture consists of the following:
Worker threads that execute the callback functions,
Waiter threads that wait on multiple wait handles,
A work queue
A default thread pool for each process, and
A worker factory that manages the worker threads.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686760%28v=vs.85%29.aspx